# mysqldump export data is horizontal, as it is to be placed vertically ... (lines to columns)

Tags: mysql, command

i am using mysqldump command line

```
mysqldump -uroot -p "MY_DATABASE" --compact --complete-insert ps_group_lang > BackUP.sql
```

**and as it turned out I get this:**

[output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wenVc.png)

**I would like to stay like this**

[i need this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4vbr.png)

***Thank you for all your help..***

Comment: I don't understand the question both images end up with the same result in the db.

Comment: the result is the same, it deals with the VALUE
be row by row ..

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: that the records (VALUES) of each table be placed vertically, not Linear (horizontal)

phpMyAdmin does it that way, but we occupy it if it is possible to join it with mysqldump

Comment: No it's not mysqldump is not formatable.